# Getting Leiningen running on Mac OS X 10.7.2

Tags: java, macos, clojure, leiningen

I installed Leiningen on Mac OS X 10.7.2 via MacPorts:

```
$ lein version
Leiningen 1.6.1.1 on Java 1.6.0_29 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

I also have `clojure` and `clojure-contrib` packages installed:

```
$ sudo port installed clojure*
The following ports are currently installed:
  clojure @1.3.0_0 (active)
  clojure-contrib @1.2.0_0 (active)
```

To test my environment, I generated a sample `helloworld` project, [as described here by Zef Hemel](http://zef.me/2470/building-clojure-projects-with-leiningen). Here is the `project.clj` file:

```
(defproject helloworld "0.1"
    :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure
                      "1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT"]
                   [org.clojure/clojure-contrib
                      "1.2.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
    :main helloworld)
```

And here is the `helloworld.clj` file:

```
(ns helloworld
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "Hello world!"))
```

When I try to compile this project, I get several update messages...

```
$ pwd
/Users/alexreynolds/helloworld

$ sudo lein compile
[INFO] snapshot org.clojure:clojure:1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT: checking for updates from clojars
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure/1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT/clojure-1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT.pom from clojars
[INFO] snapshot org.clojure:clojure-contrib:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT: checking for updates from clojars
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure-contrib/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/clojure-contrib-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom from clojars
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure/1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT/clojure-1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT.jar from clojars
Downloading: org/clojure/clojure-contrib/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/clojure-contrib-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar from clojars
```

...and then a whole bunch of errors:

```
An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
 Diagnosis:

Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
----------
1) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
        2) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT

2) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure-contrib -Dversion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure-contrib -Dversion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
        2) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT

----------
2 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact:
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  clojars (http://clojars.org/repo/),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

----------
2 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact:
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  clojars (http://clojars.org/repo/),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
        at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
        at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:235)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:254)
        at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:270)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:377)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
----------
1) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure -Dversion=1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0
        2) org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.3.0-master-SNAPSHOT

2) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

...

----------
2 required artifacts are missing.

for artifact:
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  clojars (http://clojars.org/repo/),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)


    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:324)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.doExecute(DependenciesTask.java:170)
    ... 38 more
```

I have tried to `self-install`:

```
$ sudo lein self-install
Downloading Leiningen now...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 9161k  100 9161k    0     0  1889k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 2580k
```

But on the second attempt to `compile`, I get the same warnings and errors.

What should I try in order to fix this? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SNAPSHOT` releases are typically deployed to separate maven repositories. Recent versions of Leiningen don't include Clojure snapshot repositories in the default list of repositories.

Unless you have a good reason to use `SNAPSHOT` dependencies, you should list stable versions in `project.clj` instead:

```
(defproject helloworld "0.1"
    :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]
    :main helloworld)
```

(I removed `clojure-contrib` since version `1.2.0` isn't compatible with `clojure 1.3` and your sample project isn't using it anyway.)